# Sharepoint Calculated Column Outputting string;# before result

Tags: string, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

I'm outputting a calculated column in a blog archive webpart in sharepoint 2013 in the format of 'MMMM, YYYY' so Im getting a list of dates...however each one has 'string;#' before it...is there anyway to remove this? Ive been looking for a answer for ages.

Example:

```
string;#November, 2013
string;#October, 2013
string;#November, 2013
```

Comment: You get 'string;#' string because you are using calculated column. Have you tried to modify xslt or js of the web part?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

> =SUBSTITUTE([Date Column],"string;#","")